# Converse of Cauchy's Theorem (special case)

Tags: complex-analysis, homotopy-theory, complex-integration

Let $\gamma_0, \gamma_1$ denote two curves in $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ that both start and end at 1. I want to show that if

\begin{equation}
\int_{\gamma_0} \frac{1}{z} \ dz = \int_{\gamma_1} \frac{1}{z} \ dz,
\end{equation}
then $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_1$ are homotopic. Since the above integrals take the values $2\pi i k$ (depending on how many times the curve circles $0$). The statement makes perfectly sense to me (just by drawing some curves around $0$), but I do now know how to argue it properly. Any hints?

Comment: What are you allowed to use? For instance, do you know the fundamental group of $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$? Or of $S^1$?

Comment: No, sorry. I do not know what that is. I would rather solve it without resorting to advanced topological concepts.

Comment: This could be tedious if you do not have extra assumptions but one way is to first approximate by polygonal curves, cut self intersections (homotopically) and reduce to a system of piecewise linear curves that have simple image (though you may go a few times around in the parametrization) then condense all in one curve you go around $k_j$ times for each $j=0,1$. Then the integral equality shows the equality of the $k$'s and you are done

Comment: Yes, it is doable without more assumption but it is tedious, are you willing to assume that your paths are of class $\mathcal{C}^1$?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I feared that it could get very tedious. My informal argument would have been that since the integrals over both curves are equal they must circle around $0$ equally often (clockwise and counterclockwise). A closed curve that circles around $0$ must consist of several closed curves around $0$. When considering one of these closed curves around $0$ of $\gamma_0$ and one of $\gamma_1$ we can define 'interiors' between these two curves which do not contain $0$, so there I can find a continuous function for the homotopic property. But this is a mess and very informal...

Comment: @RobinCarlier Yes, that would be fine, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without loss of generality, you can assume that both $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_1$ have their values in $S^1 = \{z \in \mathbb{C}, |z|^2 = 1\}$. This can indeed be achieved through an homotopy that projects radially each point of $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ to the corresponding point of the sphere.

So $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_1$ are path from $[0,1]$ to $S^1$ such that $\gamma_i(0) = \gamma_i(1) = 1$ for $i = 0, 1$. I will use the following fact, commonly known as the  "path lifting property". If $\gamma$ is a path with such property, then, there exists a unique path $\tilde{\gamma}: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\tilde{\gamma}(0) = 0$ and $\gamma(t) = \mathrm{exp}(\mathrm{i}\tilde{\gamma}(t))$ for all $t$. Moreover, $\tilde{\gamma}$ has the same differentiability as $\gamma$. So we can take $\tilde{\gamma}_i$ two such path for $i = 0, 1$.

Since $\gamma_i(1) = 1$, $\tilde{\gamma}_i(1) = 2\pi n$ for some $n$. The claim is of course that this $n$ is actually what you called $k$, i.e that $n = \frac{1}{2\mathrm{i}\pi}\int_{\gamma_0}\frac{1}{z}\mathrm{d}z$. This can be computed explicitly since \begin{align*}
\int_{\gamma_0}\frac{1}{z}\mathrm{d}z &= \int_{0}^1\frac{\gamma_0'(t)}{\gamma_0(t)}dt\\
&= \int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{i}\tilde{\gamma}_0'(t)\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\tilde{\gamma}_0(t)}}{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\tilde{\gamma}_0(t)}}dt\\
&= \mathrm{i(\tilde{\gamma}_0(1) - \tilde{\gamma}_0(0))}\\
&= 2\mathrm{i}\pi n
\end{align*}
And similarly for $\gamma_1$.

Now the problem becomes easier since we are reduced to finding an homotopy between $\tilde{\gamma}_0$ and $\tilde{\gamma}_1$ that leaves goth endpoint fixed. Since they both lie in a line, the most straightforward map $H(t, p) = p\tilde{\gamma}_0(t) + (1 - p)\tilde{\gamma}_1(t)$ will do. Composing this homotopy with $x \mapsto \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}x}$ will give an homotopy between $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_1$.

If you wish so, I can include a quick proof of the "path lifting lemma" I used.

---

Edit: As you requested, I will sketch a proof of the "path lifting lemma". Its exact statement is as follows: Let $\gamma: [0,1] \to S^1$, be a continuous path, and let $\theta_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ be such that $\gamma(0)=\mathrm{exp}(\mathrm{i}\theta_0)$. Then, there exists a unique continuous map $\tilde{\gamma}: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\tilde{\gamma}(0) = \theta_0$ and, for all $t \in [0,1]$, $\gamma(t) = \mathrm{exp}(\mathrm{i}\tilde{\gamma}(t))$.

The proof is "piece by piece". $\tilde{\gamma}$ can be thought as a "continuous argument function" for $\gamma$. First, let's assume that $\gamma$ always have a real part strictly greater than $0$. Then, there is a well-defined formula for $\tilde{\gamma}$, namely, it is $\tan^{—1}\left(\frac{\mathrm{Im}(\gamma(t))}{\mathrm{Re}(\gamma(t))}\right) + 2k\pi$ where $k$ is so that the condition on $\theta_0$ is satisfied. This gives a continuous formula for $\tilde{\gamma}$, and is the only one possible with the extra condition on $\tilde{\gamma}(0)$. So we proved the lemma in this special case.

Now if $\gamma$ is such that its image is contained in any strict "half-circle", we can multiply gamma by some complex number lying on the circle to rotate it and to fall in the previous case, we only need to keep track on what it does to $\theta_0$ to keep the condition, but this pose no problem. So we can prove the lemma for any $\gamma$ that has a "small enough" image.

Finally, for any path $\gamma$, by compactness of $[0,1]$ and by continuity of $\gamma$, there are a finite number of points $t_0 = 0 < t_1 < \cdots < t_{n-1} < 1 = t_n$ such that $\gamma_{|[t_i,t_{i+1}]}$ has a "small enough" image in the previous sense. By a linear change of variable, we may apply successively the lemma, first to $\gamma_0 = \gamma_{|[0,t_1]}$ with $\tilde{\gamma}_0(0) = \theta_0$, then with $\gamma_1 = \gamma_{|[t_1,t_2]}$ with the condition $\tilde{\gamma}_1(t_1) = \tilde{\gamma}_0(t_0)$, and so on. We can then glue those maps to get a well-defined map $\tilde{\gamma}: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$. Uniqueness at each step shows uniqueness of $\tilde{\gamma}$. Note that all along we only used  inverse tangent, quotients and some rotations, so if $\gamma$ was $\mathcal{C}^k$, then so is $\tilde{\gamma}$.

Comment: Thanks! A quick proof of the path lifting lemma would be great and help a lot!

Comment: @FelixP. I added the proof. It might seem long, but it boils down to "Locally, there is only one way to construct such a lift and it's given by a continuous function, so let's glue those "local" lifts to get a full lift".

Comment: I got one last question after all: Could explain in a bit more detail why I can assume that $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_1$ take values on the unit circle? What exactly do you mean by "there is a homotopy that projects radially every point..." Is it possible to write down that homotopy explicitly? Thanks!

Comment: @FelixP. Let's do it for $\gamma_0$, since $\gamma_0$ does not take the value $0$, the path $\eta: t \mapsto \frac{\gamma_0(t)}{|\gamma_(t_0)|}$ is well-defined an has its value in the unit circle. Now, you have an homotopy from $\gamma_0$ to $\eta$, namely, $H(t,p) = \frac{\gamma_0(t)}{p|\gamma_0(t)| + (1-p)}$. Since $|\gamma_0(t)| > 0$, the denominator will never vanish. At a fixed $t$, it just looks like we are dragging $\gamma_0(t)$ to the unit circle in a straight line orthogonal to the circle. This is what I mean by "radially".

Comment: @FelixP. And since we are coming back to this, I can also add a small comment regarding the fact that we assumed the path are smooth: we can do without this assumption. Roughly, by the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, the path can be approximated uniformy by a polynomial path (say, a polynomial $P$). It can be verified that if the polynomial path is close enough to $\gamma$, then the same kind of homotopy $(H(p,t) = (1-p)\gamma(t) + pP(t))$ will reduce to the smooth case. The only non-trivial point is that the $P(0)$ should be $1$ so that you keep the fact that your paths start at $1$.